# Гибернация и hiberfil.sys

Tags: windows, hdd, восстановление

Сразу к делу.

Компьютер ушел в гибернацию, потом включение компьютера.. заставка "Восстановление Windows". Загрузился, ок - всё.

Вопрос. Можно ли второй раз запустить "Восстановление Windows" знаю, что на C:\ лежит файл куда всё пишется hiberfil.sys.

Comment: hiberfil.sys хранит дамп оперативной памяти и восстановление тут именно запущенных процессов, а не самой винды. Объясните подробнее в чем суть вопроса :)

Comment: @gil9red, вопрос как запустить гибернацию Windows второй раз туже самую? Там у меня открытые тестовые блокноты (после гибернации я не успел сохранить на жесткий диск).

Comment: @gil9red, поскольку случился BSOD, и у HDD битые сектора загрузочного сектора. Поэтому интересует как запустить повторно гибернацию? Есть возможность перенести на другой диск жесткий этот файл, и за пустить на моем же компьютере.